# Pegar ID de um video do YouTube pela URL

Tags: php

Tenho essa string "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw" e quero pegar apenas o ID, ou seja, apartir de "?v="

Como posso fazer isso em PHP?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pode usar [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) para extrair os fragmentos de uma url e combinar com [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) que converte uma querystring válida em um array associativo (`$param`).

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3eZEtwQVI8&list=UUdm1fwk5iqteE0MVOBUuE8Q%22';
$itens = parse_url ($url);
parse_str($itens['query'], $params);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($params);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [v] => Y3eZEtwQVI8
    [list] => UUdm1fwk5iqteE0MVOBUuE8Q"
)
```

**[Exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tz5r-4w4j)**

Comment: Essa eu gostei, pq por enquanto é a única que funciona independentemente de quantos parâmetros foram fornecidos, e da ordem deles. Basta pegar o `$params['v']` que o resultado vai ser sempre consistente.

Comment: Alternativamente pode-se informar PHP_URL_QUERY como segundo argumento de parse_url() para se ter apenas a querystring.

Answer (score 5):

Pode usar o `explode`

```
$video  = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw";
$id = explode("?v=", $video);
```

Outros exemplos [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)

Comment: Obrigado pela respota! Mas e se, por acaso, a string fosse: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3eZEtwQVI8&list=UUdm1fwk5iqteE0MVOBUuE8Q" e eu, ainda, quisesse pegar apenas a ID do video?; Que no caso acabaria em '&'?

Answer (score 3):

Pode utilizar `regex` para extrair o ID:

```
$patternRegex = "/http[s]?:\\/\\/www\\.youtube\\.com\\/watch\\?v=(\\w+)/";
$urlYoutube = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw";

preg_match($patternRegex, $urlYoutube, $matches);
```

Veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/tL5pD8/1) a funcionar com o seu exemplo.

Explicando o `$patternRegex`:

- `/http[s]?:\\/\\/www\\.youtube\\.com\\/watch\\?v=` : Esta parte procura o inicio da URL.
- `[s]?` - Indica que o caracter s pode ocorrer uma ou zero vezes.
- `(\\w+)/` : Esta parte captura todos os caracteres alfanuméricos e *underscores* que existirem após o ?=v ate ao fim da URL.

Comment: Uma dúvida: Toda url do youtube terá o `https`? Pq se por acaso alguma vir com `http`, seu regex não funciona mais.

Comment: Pode alterar o regex para suportar urls sem SSL. Veja a resposta editada.

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar assim que qualquer formato da url ira funcionar

```
function YoutubeID($url)
{
    if(strlen($url) > 11)
    {
        if (preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match)) 
        {
            return $match[1];
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: apesar de a resposta nao estar bem detalhada funciona, parabens.