# URL Amigável: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare parse_path()

Tags: php

Tenho este código em um documento vars.php pra implementar uma url amigável:

```
<?php
//var_dump($_SERVER);
function parse_path() {
    $path = array();
    if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        $request_path = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        $path['base'] = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '\/');
        $path['call_utf8'] = substr(urldecode($request_path[0]), strlen($path['base']) + 1);
        $path['call'] = utf8_decode($path['call_utf8']);
        if ($path['call'] == basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
            $path['call'] = '';
        }
        $path['call_parts'] = explode('/', $path['call']);

        $path['query_utf8'] = urldecode($request_path[1]);
        $path['query'] = utf8_decode(urldecode($request_path[1]));
        $vars = explode('&', $path['query']);
        foreach ($vars as $var) {
          $t = explode('=', $var);
          $path['query_vars'][$t[0]] = $t[1];
        }
    }
    return $path;
}

$path_info = parse_path();
echo '<pre>'.print_r($path_info, true).'</pre>';

?>

<?php
switch($path_info['call_parts'][0]) {
    case 'aempresa': include 'aempresa.php';
        break;
    case 'contato': include 'contato.php';
        break;
    case 'cumeeiras': include 'cumeeiras.php';
        break;
    case 'informacoes-tecnicas': include 'informacoes_tecnicas.php';
        break;
    case 'orcamento': include 'orcamento.php';
        break;
    case 'telha-ondulada-natural': include 'telha_ondulada_natural.php';
        break;
    case 'telha-pre-pintada': include 'telha_pre_pintada.php';
        break;
    case 'telha-termoacustica-semi-sanduiche': include 'telha_termoacustica_semi_sanduiche.php';
        break;
    case 'telha-trapezoidal-natural': include 'telha_trapezoidal_natural.php';
        break;
    case 'telhas-termoacusticas-sanduiche': include 'telhas_termoacusticas_sanduiche.php';
        break;
    case 'vantagens': include 'vantagens.php';
        break;
  default:
    include 'index.php';
}

?>
```

Porém esta imprimindo o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare parse_path() (previously declared in /var/www/html/formaremetais.com.br/web/teste/vars.php:4) in /var/www/html/formaremetais.com.br/web/teste/vars.php on line 4

Endereço para análise: http://www.formaremetais.com.br/teste/

Inclui o código em todas as páginas do site utilizando require

Obs: o site não esta separado em includes.

Porém está ocorrendo o erro descrito acima.

Preciso de uma ajuda para reparar este erro e descobrir o que esta acontecendo. Obrigado.

Comment: simples voce esta declarando mais de uma vez o parse_path

Comment: Mas como faço isso? Sou completamente iniciante.

Comment: O objetivo do código é pegar a queryString e outras partes da url? Pode usar `parse_str()` & `parse_url()` como em: [Pegar ID de um video do YouTube pela URL](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43810/91)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Cannot redeclare function nomeDaFuncao

O erro é bem claro, diz que o nome da função foi declarado duas ou mais vezes dentro do mesmo escopo no caso global, lembra que é possível definir nomes de funções iguais porém em namespace diferentes.

Para resolver verifique o arquivo citado no erro e remova a definição dessa função, para melhorar a organição deixe apenas um arquivo com a criação de funções, não espalhe elas em arquivos diferentes.