# Como extrair o ID de vídeo das urls do youtube?

Tags: php

Sou iniciante em php e meu problema é o seguinte.

Esse é o código atualmente

```
$link = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rW-44KuoAdA
 $id = explode('?v=', $link);
$get_video_info = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='.$id[1].'&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US';
$get_video_info = curl($get_video_info);
$thumbnail_url = $title = $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map = $type = $url = '';
```

Eu preciso que o explode faça isso:

```
$link = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rW-44KuoAdA ou https://youtu.be/rW-44KuoAdA
 $id = explode('?v=', $link);
$get_video_info = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='.$id[1].'&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US';
$get_video_info = curl($get_video_info);
```

Como poderei fazer isso?

No caso fazer o explode reconhecer duas URLs diferentes.

@Edit

As duas resposta funcionaram mas resolvi o problema assim.

```
    if( preg_match('/^https:\/\/w{3}?.youtube.com\//', $my_id) ){
        $url   = parse_url($my_id);
        $my_id = NULL;
        if( is_array($url) && count($url)>0 && isset($url['query']) && !empty($url['query']) ){
            $parts = explode('&',$url['query']);
            if( is_array($parts) && count($parts) > 0 ){
                foreach( $parts as $p ){
                    $pattern = '/^v\=/';
                    if( preg_match($pattern, $p) ){
                        $my_id = preg_replace($pattern,'',$p);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if( !$my_id ){
                echo '<p>No video id passed in</p>';
                exit;
            }
        }else{
            echo '<p>Invalid url</p>';
            exit;
        }
    }elseif( preg_match('/^https?:\/\/youtu.be/', $my_id) ) {
        $url   = parse_url($my_id);
        $my_id = NULL;
        $my_id = preg_replace('/^\//', '', $url['path']);
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>No video id passed in</p>';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Você quer adicionar o .com.br? ou apenas remover o .com e deixar .br?

Comment: Aqui é BR, como assim o que você deseja fazer com esse código talveze tenha outra função mais adequada que o `explode()`

Comment: `explode`? por que você não tenta usar o `implode`?

Comment: eu tenho um campo onde eu coloco um link o explode pega pra mim o que tem depois do .com/ eu gostaria que ele quando eu colocasse um link .com.br/ ele pegasse também.

Comment: Mostra uma exemplo de link ai

Comment: Outra alternativa - melhor ao meu ver - seria usar [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php) para pegar o `path` da url.

Comment: @PapaCharlie também [desconfio](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43818/91)

Comment: @rray, até removi meu comentário anterior, ficou com cara de gambiarra depois de lembrar do `parse_url`. rs

Comment: $link = $my_id;
$id = explode('?v=', $link);
$get_video_info = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='.$id[1].'&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US';
$get_video_info = curl($get_video_info);
$thumbnail_url = $title = $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map = $type = $url = '';
parse_str($get_video_info);

Comment: O que é esse codigo?

Comment: um script para download do youtube obs: parte dele

Comment: Ele faz parte da pergunta ou foi como resolveu o problema?

Comment: faz parte da pergunta só que o problema ainda persiste, foi mais para ilustrar o problema, eu quero é que o explode me retorne um valor de duas urls diferentes e não sei como fazer.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque esse código, se tiver mais alguma explicação tbm adicione

Comment: O que pretende fazer não conseguirá usando somente `explode()`. A pergunta está focada na função `explode()`. O certo seria perguntar como obter o id do video nas URLs do youtube, incluindo short URL e domínios diferentes. Isso é mais complexo do que o simples uso do `explode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Código retiradodo SO-en:

```
if (preg_match('/youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([^\&\?\/]+)/', $url, $id)) {
  $values = $id[1];
} else if (preg_match('/youtube\.com\/embed\/([^\&\?\/]+)/', $url, $id)) {
  $values = $id[1];
} else if (preg_match('/youtube\.com\/v\/([^\&\?\/]+)/', $url, $id)) {
  $values = $id[1];
} else if (preg_match('/youtu\.be\/([^\&\?\/]+)/', $url, $id)) {
  $values = $id[1];
}
else if (preg_match('/youtube\.com\/verify_age\?next_url=\/watch%3Fv%3D([^\&\?\/]+)/', $url, $id)) {
    $values = $id[1];
} else {   
// not an youtube video
}
```

original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594943/regex-pattern-to-get-the-youtube-video-id-from-any-youtube-url

Answer (score 0):

Eu criei uma função para o seu problema, estude ela, e pode implementar mais formatos de url acrescentando após os if/elses no caso eu criei somente para o seu caso de 2 formatos de url.

```
 <?php

    function PegarIDYoutube($link) {
       // Explode formato ?v
       $link_formato_1 = explode("?v",$link);
       // Checa se o formato ?v existe se existir retorna o id
       if(is_array($link_formato_1)) {
          return $link_formato_1[1];
       // Senao ele tenta outro formato
       } else {
          // Explode formato .be/
          $link_formato_2 = explode(".be/",$link);

          // Checa se o formato link e .be se existir retorna o id
          if(is_array($link_formato_2)) {
            return $link_formato_2[1];
          // se não retorna false (link nao existente);
          } else {
            return false;
          }
       }

    }

 ?>
```