# removendo parte de uma string com php

Tags: php

Galera tenho uma variável com o seguinte link:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/z1n34sRv1-A
```

Preciso remover tudo que vem antes do embed, ou seja preciso do seguinte id:

```
z1n34sRv1-A
```

Como posso fazer isso com php?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43810/91

Comment: nesse caso não vai dar certo porque não é um parametro GET ele faz parte da url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o explode para dividir a String pelas barras e pegar a última posição que é o count do array:

```
$url_parts = explode("/", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/z1n34sRv1-A");
echo $url_parts[count($url_parts)-1];
```

Comment: perfeito, funcionou 100%

Answer (score 5):

Voce pode fazer desse jeito:

```
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/z1n34sRv1-A";
$url = explode("embed/", $url);
$embed = $url[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar:

```
 substr($string,$start,$length);
```

$string = variável,
$start = começo da variável onde irá começar o corte da string em inteiro,
$length= fim da variável em inteiro,

Digamos que o padrão da URL tenha 25 caracteres, então ficaria desta forma:

```
substr($url,25,strlen($url));
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o `strrpos` para detectar a última `/` da url e, com `substr`, extraia a parte desejada:

```
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/z1n34sRv1-A';

substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1)
```

A função `strrpos` encontra a última ocorrência de `/` e retorna a posição. Como precisamos pegar o que vem depois disso, é necessário adicionar um +1.

Ainda utilizando uma linha, você pode facilitar usando `array_reverse`, para pegar apenas o último elemento do `array` gerado pelo `explode`.

```
 current(array_reverse(explode('/', $url)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
$url_parts = explode("/", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/z1n34sRv1-A");

echo end($url_parts);
```