# Usar split e trocar a chave do array?

Tags: php, array, spliterator

Ao usar a função `split` em uma string obviamente as chaves serão enumeradas de 0 até ... mas eu gostaria de escolher qual deve ser a chave, usando justamente uma das palavras que estará na string, exemplo para ajudar a simplificar:

```
$string = "key1=xxx&key2=xxx&key3=xxx&key4=xxx ...";
```

Ao usar o split separando a string no `&` eu gostaria que as chaves fossem ordenadas conforme o "key" e ficasse assim:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => xxx1
    [key2] => xxx2
    [key3] => xxx3
    [key4] => xxx4
)
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Acho que [isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43818/91) pode ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado @rray só o parse_str já foi suficiente para resolver o problema :)