# Como dividir um link em "varias partes"?

Tags: php

Eu tenho o seguinte link:

```
https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=377361903&token=9Q0WYuq0
```

O que pretendo fazer, é armazenar o valor de partner em uma variavel designada por `$partner`, e o valor de token, armazenado numa variavel designada por `$token`.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Utilize [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php) e depois [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-str.php) da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php

    $url = "https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=377361903&token=9Q0WYuq0";
    $result = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($result['query'], $var);

    echo $var['partner'];
    echo $var['token'];
```

[***Exemplo IDEONE***](http://ideone.com/79AKys)

<sub>Referencias</sub>

- [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php)
- [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma

```
$url = parse_url("https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=377361903&token=9Q0WYuq0");
parse_str($url['query'], $par);
```

`$par` agora é um `array` com os dados que você quer coletar, ao dar um `print_r` nele:

```
Array
(
    [partner] => 377361903
    [token] => 9Q0WYuq0
)
```

Para chamar basta usar `$par["partner"]` ou `$par["token"]` para obter acesso as informações do `array`

Referência

> [Pegar ID de um video do YouTube pela URL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43810/pegar-id-de-um-video-do-youtube-pela-url/43818#43818)
>
> [PHP - parse_url](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php)
>
> [PHP - parse_str](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-str.php)